# подтверждение платежа при оплате через яндекс форму

Tags: yandex-money

Есть [яндекс форма для оплаты](https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-buttons/reference/forms-docpage/).

Подскажите, после оплаты можно сделать редирект на сайт и принять POST данне с формы заполнения?

Comment: А кто вам отдаст POST данные с формы? Тем более там различная конфиденциальная информация типа номера карты, ФИО владельца и т.п.

Comment: тогда нужно использовать яндекс кассу?